# Linux Bash Script - Sort Sequential Files to Sequential Folders

Tags: linux, bash, script

I have a sequence of 1000s of files named as follows:

```
file01-01-01, file01-01-02 etc.
file01-02-01, file01-02-02 etc.
file02-01-01, file02-02-02 etc.
```

I would like to sort the files into folder named as follows:

```
dir01-01 (containing files01-01*)
dir01-02 (containing files01-01*)
dir02-01 (containing files02-01*)
```

I know I can reduce the time it takes me to do this via a line like:

```
mkdir dir01-01; for f in file01-01*; mv "$f" dir01-01; done
```

But the above will only reduce the sorting time slightly, how can I automate the whole sorting operation?

I know I need to do something with let N ++ but not sure how to incorporate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. First, I created test files like this:

```
touch file01-01-01 file01-01-02 file01-02-01 file01-02-02 file02-01-01 file02-02-02
```

Confirmed they existed by using `ls -1` and the output looked like this:

```
file01-01-01
file01-01-02
file01-02-01
file01-02-02
file02-01-01
file02-02-02
```

Then I ran this Bash script within the directory containing those files:

```
find . -type f |\
  while read FULL_FILE_PATH
  do
    FIRST_TWO_DIGITS=$(echo "${FULL_FILE_PATH}" | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}');
    if [ ! -z "$FIRST_TWO_DIGITS" -a "$FIRST_TWO_DIGITS" != " " ]; then
      DIR=dir"${FIRST_TWO_DIGITS}";
      mkdir -p "${DIR}";
      mv "${FULL_FILE_PATH}" "${DIR}";
    fi
  done
```

With that done, I checked the directory with `ls -1` like this and here is the returned output:

```
dir01-01
dir01-02
dir02-01
dir02-02
```

So the directories are there but to confirm the files were copied I ran that `ls` command with an `*` like this: `ls -1 *`. And here is the output:

```
dir01-01:
file01-01-01
file01-01-02

dir01-02:
file01-02-01
file01-02-02

dir02-01:
file02-01-01

dir02-02:
file02-02-02
```

Comment: Nice thanks a lot for the breakdown, now to investigate why that all works..